s3.list_objects_v2 is returning results which don't appear in any S3 bucket
I'm using S3 for file storage of image uploads. Different buckets host multiple images from user uploads.
I am iterating over a list of a given user (any user) - and the results returned from the request include 50%-60% of files which I cannot find in the S3 bucket when I access the console.
This is happening on multiple user buckets - so it's not something isolated. Any idea what these files returned are and if they really exist?

This is not normal behaviour. Can you provide some examples? If you make a new bucket with some files and list the contents, is it correct? I wonder whether these mysterious files are 'directories'? You see, when somebody clicks the 'Create folder' button in the management console, it creates a zero-length object with the name of the folder. This forces the folder to appear even if it is empty. These files will appear in list_objects_v2() calls, but will be hidden in the console.
